# MongoDB "Cursor not found" even with no-timeout

Tags: mongodb, go

*Reported [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24899), but I was told to post on StackOverflow*

I'm trying to read the users from a forum database. Eventually, I want to put the data into PostgreSQL, but for now it just discards the data after reading it. My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/BenLubar/07335d7e6b4ab939c02517d59b3f8b80).

The database is being told not to expire the cursor [here](https://gist.github.com/BenLubar/07335d7e6b4ab939c02517d59b3f8b80#file-read_nodebb_database-go-L36), which calls [this function](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2/session.go#L1670-L1681), which sets no-timeout.

However, I'm getting an error [here](https://gist.github.com/BenLubar/07335d7e6b4ab939c02517d59b3f8b80#file-read_nodebb_database-go-L444) that says `Cursor not found, cursor id: 28781399268` (the numbers change on every run) after going through about 96k of the 141k users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the Go MongoDB driver has a bug. I've submitted a fix here: https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/pull/295

It was setting the NoCursorTimeout flag on the wire message, but not the noCursorTimeout property on the query.